# django - How can I filter in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

```
class User(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = RetrieveLocalSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.filter(
        fields_1=True,
        fields_2=False 
    )

class LocalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = User
         fields = ('field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3',)
```

The API did not work as it I wish. When I tried get user that does not have the property i want, it still returned the result.

I even tried override that function but it did not work too.

```
    def get_queryset(self): 
    return User.objects.filter(
        is_localguide=True,
        state=PROFILE_STATE.PUBLISHED
    )
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question correctly you wish to get list of instances in your view (using Django Rest Framework). The problem is that your view is inheriting from a `generics.RetrieveAPIView`. This view class calls `self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)` method which returns you an object, not queryset. I think that you should inherit your view from a `ListAPIView` class. This class inherits `ListModelMixin` which

> Provides a .list(request, *args, **kwargs) method, that implements listing a queryset.

So your code will be looking like this:

```
class User(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = RetrieveLocalSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.filter(
        fields_1=True,
        fields_2=False 
    )
```

See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview for more information.

You may either define your queryset in a view or override `get_queryset` method:

> queryset - The queryset that should be used for returning objects from this view. Typically, you must either set this attribute, or override the get_queryset() method. If you are overriding a view method, it is important that you call get_queryset() instead of accessing this property directly, as queryset will get evaluated once, and those results will be cached for all subsequent requests.

You may find more information here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview

Hope this will help)